# How to fuzzily search for dictionary words?

Tags: nlp

Suppose I have a dictionary of words, {'cat', 'cot', 'catalyst'}, and a character similarity relation f(x, y)

```
f(x, y) = 1, if x and y are similar
        = 0, otherwise
```

These "similarities" can be specified by the programmer.
such that, say,

```
f('t', 'l') = 1
f('a', 'o') = 1
f('f', 't') = 1
```

but,

```
f('a', 'z') = 0
etc.
```

Now if we have a query 'cofatyst', the algorithm should report the following matches:

```
('cot', 0)
('cat', 0)
('catalyst', 0)
```

where the number is the 0-based starting index of the match found. I have tried the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm), and while it works great for exact matching and in the case when a character has relatively less number of "similar" characters, its performance drops exponentially as we increase the number of similar characters for a character. Can anyone point me to a better way of doing this? Fuzziness is an absolute necessity, and it must take in to account character similarities(i.e., not blindly depend on just edit-distances).

Comment: So basically, you want some kind of minimum-edit distance that takes into account that certain characters (like characters close together on a keyboard) are more likely to be swapped? My gut is telling me you're going to get a much better response on StackOverflow.

Comment: correct! And the notion of similar characters may be different (e.g., when you OCR some stuff, an l is more likely to be misread as a 't' or 'i' than being misread as an 'a') Okay, asking on SO as well

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fuzzily search for a dictionary word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333766/how-to-fuzzily-search-for-a-dictionary-word) You apparently posted on both SO and linguistics.stackexchange. The question on the latter was then migrated here.

Answer (score 1):

levenshtein distance is similar to what you are looking for although may not be as fine grained. You could reimplement a more controlled version of that algorithm however I'm sure.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: This is a start, but the problem is, with a huge dictionary, how do I search for dictionary *substrings* within the query? The Levenshtein distance calculation algorithm can be modified to accommodate that: http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/12/01/fuzzy-substring-matching-with-levenshtein-distance-in-python/ But, it only gives the least Levenshtein distance of the substring matched - does not give the position of the match(es) out of the box. I think I am close, and if there is enough brainstorming here, we can come up with something neat.